# Latex error: Control sequence \c_backslash_str already defined - l3str.sty

Tags: errors, csquotes

Two days ago I updated my miktex packages(using the auto update), as well as my editor (TeXstudio). After the update a document of mine simply stops rendering. On another PC of mine that wasn't updated the file renders just fine.

The error log I'm getting is the following:

```
'babel/polyglossia' detected but 'csquotes' missing.

line 83: LaTeX error: "kernel/command-already-defined" Control sequence \c_backslash_str already defined. For immediate help type H <return>. ...st:Nx \c_backslash_str { \cs_to_str:N \\ }
```

This last error comes from a file: `l3str.sty` (and line 83 seems to be in that file)

There are other warnings as well, but they were there before the problem
You can find the complete code for this document [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yf88zeqvmos4jmm/document.tex?dl=0)
There are extra text documents that are loaded loaded as well. Though I doubt the error is caused by them.

Now my questions are:

- Can I fix this problem and use the new release?
- If not, how do I easily roll back the old release?

My sincerest thanks for taking the time to read this,

Comment: You can't roll back in miktex. Did you run the update manager in admin *and* user mode? Btw: I won't try your whole code. If the problem persist make a minimal example.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show a minimal example showing the issue?

Comment: This is going to be a version mismatch: as @egreg says, make an example and edit in it and the log file.

Answer (score 3):

---Update---
Dear All, thanks for the suggestions.
I made a minimal example and tested not loading certain packages. It turns out that when I first load the mhchem package and only afterwards the xpatch one the error disappears. So changing this solved my problem.

Minimal example of non working code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,notitlepage]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{a4wide}                     % Iets meer tekst op een bladzijde
\usepackage{xpatch} %needed for patcjh of () with IEEE style
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}          % Voor elegante scheikundige formules
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Minimal example of working code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,notitlepage]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{a4wide}                     % Iets meer tekst op een bladzijde
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}          % Voor elegante scheikundige formules
\usepackage{xpatch} %needed for patcjh of () with IEEE style
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Ps: I always use the admin updater, is this the correct one to use?

Thanks for the suggestions,

Kind regards,

Jasper

Comment: The `xpatch` package needs `\c_backslash_str`, but as `l3str` is still in the experimental branch, I don't load it; however `mhchem` does, so if `mchem` is loaded after `xpatch`, as soon as `l3str` is loaded, an error is issued. This doesn't happen with the reverse order, because `xpatch` defines `\c_backslash_str` only if still undefined.

Comment: For reference: I just ran into the same issue when loading `imakeidx (2013/07/11)` before `mhchem (2015/07/07)`. Loading `mhchem` first works here aswell.